Why is the term "呼吸" (breathing) structured this way? Instead of "吸呼"?
This may seem like a odd question, but I am wondering why the Chinese for breathing is "呼吸" and not "吸呼".
As recently I just learnt that "呼" means "to exhale". It's similar to "吐气"。
While "吸" just mean "inhale".
This get me thinking, usually we inhale first before exhaling. So wouldn't "吸呼" make more sense?
I would like someone to debunk my statement, explaining why "呼吸" is structured this way and the reasoning behind it.

"usually we inhale first before exhaling" — Isn't it just as true that we exhale first before inhaling?

This is a reasonable question and I’ve seen the same question years ago on zhihu. According to the top answers (see this and this), the order of 呼 and 吸 is determined by the tones. 呼 is 平声 and 吸 is 入声. Usually 平声 is in front of 入声.

Does it apply to? -- 上下, (up and down), 左 右, (left and right), 前后, (before and after) 输赢, (loss and win), 高低, (high and low) Except for "loss and win", I believe the order for the above phrases is the same as in English?

@WayneCheah (Correct me if I’m wrong as I’m not an expert.) I don’t think this theory can apply to your examples as their tones don’t match the pattern. The screenshot in the first link provides some more examples, e.g., 琴瑟 and 饥渴, for the theory. I believe it can apply to 南北 (different from north and south in English) as well.
